# android - could not find support-annotations.jar

Tags: android

I'm trying to sync project with Gradle. But gradle gives some error.

The error code like this : Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not find support-annotations.jar (com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/24.0.0/support-annotations-24.0.0.jar

My build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ileem.tiiu"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha2'
 compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
 compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'

 compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
 compile files('libs/jsoup-1.10.1.jar')

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to the latest version of the build tools and support libraries. You can find them [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html).